How to install PyTorch and run .pt file in Raspberry Pi 4 B?
So i am trying to implement my yolov5 object detection model "best.pt" which i trained in custom roboflow collab notebook file which i have already downloaded in my desktop since it is where i trained it. Now im trying to pass the .pt file using different methods to my raspi 4b (google drive, dropbox, etc), but it is being converted to zip archive file always which should not do. Moreover, i also cant get the right pytorch version on my raspi after trying different versions with arm/aarch compatibility. Running my python files results to showing "illegal instruction" which works again whenever i uninstall pytorch which shows incompatibility. Im also using virtual environment to ensure the safety of my system.
Is it really not possible in my situation? This is a critical moment for me since it is what i have written in my papers using pytorch.
This is my raspi version and details:
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian

64bit
aarch64
python 3.11.2


If you're getting "illegal instruction," that means you're trying to execute an incompatible binary on your raspberry pi. If you install pytorch through pip, it should handle this automatically:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
Also, if these cloud providers are zipping your model, you can still unzip it on your pi. If you really can't zip your file forwhatever reason, try using scp  to move them.

hi, i have tried install the torch using pip3, it is still showing "illegal instruction" when i tried to run any of my python files or even checking the torch version installed.
